# Unicorn Freezes on Start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, aws-opsworks

I am doing some troubleshooting to figure out why my site will not load.

I am using Amazon OopsWorks. I have an Amazon Linux server running Rails 4.2.0 and Ruby 2.2.0. I'm using Nginx and Unicorn. I have verified Nginx is running. When I try to start Unicorn with `bundle exec unicorn -E production -c /srv/www/likeminds/current/config/unicorn.rb` I do not get an error. I do not get anything, actually. That's the problem, nothing happens.

What's going on with Unicorn? It seems like it is freezing on start. Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is what is running on my server.

```
 2278 aws       20   0  323m  69m 4212 S  0.7  7.0   0:00.99 opsworks-agent     
    1 root      20   0 19596 1608 1292 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.55 init               
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd           
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.81 ksoftirqd/0        
    5 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H       
    6 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.08 kworker/u30:0      
    7 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.54 rcu_sched          
    8 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh             
    9 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0        
   10 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper            
   11 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs          
   12 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns              
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/u30:1      
   19 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xenwatch           
   20 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xenbus             
   21 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.09 kworker/0:1        
  115 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 writeback
```

Updating my Unicorn.rb file did not work. Now EC2 outputs

```
/home/deploy/.bundler/likeminds/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:657:in `parse_rackup_file': rackup file (config.ru) not readable (ArgumentError)
```

Here is the Unicorn.rb that causes Unicorn to freeze

```
# Set the working application directory
# working_directory "/path/to/your/app"
working_directory "/srv/www/likeminds/current/"

# Unicorn PID file location
# pid "/path/to/pids/unicorn.pid"
pid "/srv/www/likeminds/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Path to logs
# stderr_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
# stdout_path "/path/to/log/unicorn.log"
stderr_path "/srv/www/likeminds/shared/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/srv/www/likeminds/shared/log/unicorn.log"

# Unicorn socket
listen "/srv/www/likeminds/shared/sockets/unicorn.likeminds.sock"
listen "/srv/www/likeminds/shared/sockets/unicorn.likeminds.sock"

# Number of processes
# worker_processes 4
worker_processes 2

# Time-out
timeout 30
```

Here is the version that outputs an error, but does run successfully on my localhost.

```
if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "development"
  worker_processes 1
else
  worker_processes 3
end

timeout 30
```

### Update##

After changing permissions I was able to start Unicorn. But I am receiving errors.

```
E, [2015-05-17T00:21:47.129959 #7004] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 8943 exit 1> worker=0
I, [2015-05-17T00:21:47.130085 #7004]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2015-05-17T00:21:47.130878 #8953]  INFO -- : worker=2 spawned pid=8953
I, [2015-05-17T00:21:47.132421 #8953]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2015-05-17T00:21:47.136806 #8955]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=8955
I, [2015-05-17T00:21:47.140432 #8955]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
E, [2015-05-17T00:21:50.288644 #8950] ERROR -- : undefined local variable or method `ru' for #<LikeMinds::Apps
```

Comment: do you see any unicorn processes running in top, ps etc?

Comment: @errata what command do I use to view this information?

Comment: `ps` or `top` from a terminal

Comment: @errata posted top. It does not appear that unicorn is running.

Comment: are you able to run unicorn manually from the command line and see what happens? there should be some sort of error visible if it cannot start.

Comment: @errata I had a couple errors from some bad unicon.rb paths but I fixed those. Now when I run the start command, it freezes. I do not get any type of output in Terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77990/discussion-between-snowyetis-and-errata).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking manually from the command line should show you some output. for example, I see:

```
I, [2015-05-16T16:36:12.487217 #63958]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=9
I, [2015-05-16T16:36:12.487321 #63958]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2015-05-16T16:36:12.488381 #63958]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2015-05-16T16:36:12.489353 #63959]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=63959
I, [2015-05-16T16:36:12.489799 #63959]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2015-05-16T16:36:16.198329 #63959]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

Do you see anything using this method or in unicorn.sterr.log? Please post your unicorn config file.

SOLUTION: it appears that the pid filepath was not writable by the unicorn process. Changing the permission to allow for access by the owner of the process seems to have worked.

Comment: I think you are right. I just removed the paths in my config and it runs locally with similar output as you posted. Give me a second, while I update my instances file.

Comment: are you sure your PID file/path is writable by the user running unicorn?

Comment: It might not be, should I run chown 400 on the directory?

Comment: you can definitely try loosening up permissions to see if that is the problem. Are you able to attempt to run it manually as the user it runs as when the system launches in production mode?

Comment: I am logged in as root. I believe that is the same production user, that deploys the application.

Comment: so when you run it manually as root the master process and workers are visible the the process table?

Comment: you suggested the solution to my problem. Update your post and I will mark it as the solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: if there are still issues let me know and I'll try to help.

Comment: I do have one question regarding the error show in Unicorns output. Would you mind stepping into the chat room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77991/discussion-between-errata-and-snowyetis).